# The order of a product of two elements in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a non-commutative ring with zero $0$ and identity $1$. $a,b\in (R,+)$ are two elements of  finite order $m,n$ respectively; in notations, $ord(a)=m,ord(n)=n$. Then what is the order of the product $ab\in (R,+)$ ? In particular, if $m=n$, then is it ture that $ord(ab)=n?$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean by $\text{ord}$ the additive order, and by $ab$ the multiplication of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Ruben $4a=0$ implies that $2(a\cdot a)=0$?

Comment: It does seem to say $a,b\in (R,+)$.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you meant additive order... did you try even a single example? Like, say $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$?

$ord(2)=2$ and $ord(3)=4$, but $ord(2\cdot 2)=ord(0)$ and $ord(2\cdot 3)=ord(2)$.

In other words, the order of the product can be strange things compared to the order of the factors.  I'm sure you can go about finding other nonintuitive examples just using $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is commutative.  Assuming you mean multiplicative order.

If $a$ has order $n$ then $a^n = 1$ and therefore $a^k=1$ whenever $k$ is a multiple of $n$.  Similar formulation for $b$ of order $m$.  Then
$$
(ab)^k = a^k b^k = 1
$$
provided $k$ is a multiple of both $n$ and $m$.  So the order of $ab$ is at most $\mathrm{lcm}(n,m)$.

The order of $ab$ could be smaller than that.  For example, if $a$ is the inverse of $b$, then the order of $ab$ is $1$.

---

Of course if you mean additive order, this is not the answer.  Which is why you should fix your problem to say what order you mean.